# New pyuic from PyQt makes displaced objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, pyuic

Pyuic utility from new PyQt4 4.11.4 produces all layouts slightly displaced or compressed. That's how it initially looks in designer:

[image]

An thats how it looks after pyuic makes *.py file:

[image]

The reason is that new pyuic doesn't make `setMargin(0)` for all layouts (previously I used PyQt4.9.6 and it was set in *.py file, so it was ok). Is there any solution for this?

In the end certainly I can modify *.py files manually with script to add `setMargin(0)` for all layouts, but there should be more civilized way.. unless this is a bug.

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me. The `setMargin` function is obsolete, so `setContentsMargins` should be used instead (which is what `pyuic` currently does). You should probably post an example `ui` file if you want a proper diagnosis.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks! Now I found a workaround - if I set all margins in designer to some value and return them back to 0 - it remembers that and goes ok. Concerning `ui` file - the difference is that after "workaround" it adds to the layout      `<property name="margin"> <number>0</number>     </property>`.. I've already reinstalled python and pyqt several times and it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue and found the workaround in the comment by @funnpony. I would add an answer based on the comment for someone who come to this question by google search to get a quick workaroud.

The workaround is:

Add `<property name="margin"> <number>0</number> </property>` attribute to the item that miss .setMargin method. Or
     `<property name="leftMargin">
          <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
          <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>0</number>
       </property>`